# Kaminari : page count performance for search query

Tags: postgresql, kaminari

We have used `Kaminari` for paginating records. We have hacked `total_count` method because giving a total count is very slow after 2m + records.

```
def total_count
  @_hacked_total_count || (@_hacked_total_count = self.connection.execute("SELECT (reltuples)::integer FROM pg_class r WHERE relkind = 'r' AND relname ='#{table_name}'").first["reltuples"].to_i)
end
```

This returns approximate count of total records in the table which is fine.

However, that number is totally irrelevant when there is a *search query*.

I am looking for a fast way to return some number for search queries as well. (Doesn't need to be totally exact -- but needs to be *meaningful* (i.e. somewhat pertaining to the *search query*)

Please suggest if our approach to get total count of records as mentioned above is not correct.

P.S - We are using `Postgres` as our database provider and `Rails` as web development framework.

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE? You can upload these results at http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: @FrankHeikens you need EXPLAIN ANALYZE of query I mentioned above or of overall count query that Kaminari executes?

Comment: The overall count, the real search queries. That's where you have performance issues, so lets improve these queries.

Comment: @FrankHeikens please checkout - http://explain.depesz.com/s/aBQ. I have 12K records on my local db.

Comment: seq scan, the database is reading the whole table. Looks like there is no index on column vehicle_cd, ANALYZE hasn't been executed in a while or the table is that small it doesn't make sense to use an index scan. Please check the index and ANALYZE first.

Comment: @FrankHeikens there is an index on column vehicle_cd. Its access_method is 'btree'.

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks for your time. I finally managed to solve this. Posted my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After stumbling upon this for couple of days, I did this by using EXPLAIN query and then extracting count rows count.

Here is the code snippet I wrote:

```
query_plan = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("EXPLAIN <query>").first["QUERY PLAN"]
query_plan.match(/rows=(\d+)/)[1].to_i # returns the rows count
```

With this I can safety remove `reltuples` query.